# Am I wrong with this simple differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have been given the following differential equation:

$$(x^2 + y)dx - xdy = 0.$$

The equation turns out to be inexact, so I opted for the simple straightforward solution with the integrating factor being $1/x$, and the overall solution being:

$$y = x^2 + cx.$$

It turned out that my answer is incorrect. Why? I tried to solve it again and could not find anything wrong with what I did.

Comment: Hint:  Solve for $\frac{dy}{dx}$.

Comment: But I think that's exactly what I did - solving it as xy'-y=x^2.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite your differential equation as:

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = y' = x + \frac{y}{x}.$$

[WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=dy%2Fdx+%3D+x+%2B+%28y%2Fx%29) says the solutions are:

$$y = cx + x^2.$$

Double-checking:

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = c + 2x = x + \frac{cx + x^2}{x}$$

which validates WolframAlpha's solution.

Comment: So I was correct after all...

Comment: Yes you were!  =)